# Showing that a sequence is convergent if and only if all monotone subsequences converge to the same limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> **Claim:** A sequence $(u_{n})$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent if and only if all monotone subsequences of $(u_{n})$ converge to the same limit

The forward $(\Rightarrow)$ direction is straightforward, since if a sequence is convergent then all subsequences must converge to the same limit. But I can't see why the backward direction must imply that $(u_{n})$ converges.

Hints would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ is the limit of all the monotone subsequences and suppose the sequence $(u_n)$ does *not* converge to $L$.  Then one can pick a subsequence $v_k =u_{n_k}$ that stays outside an epsilon-neighborhood of $L$ for a suitable fixed epsilon. Now the sequence $v_k$ has a monotone subsequence that can't converge to $L$. The contradiction proves that $(u_n)$ converges to $L$ (there is no need to distinguish bounded and unbounded cases).

Answer (score 3):

$(\Leftarrow)$:   Let $a$ denote the common limit of all monotone subsequences.

1. We will use the follwing fact: every sequence in $ \mathbb R$ contains a monotone subsequence.
2. The sequence $(u_n)$ is bounded. Assume not. Show that then there is a monotone subsequence of $(u_n)$ which is unbounded, a contradiction.
3. Let $b$ an accumulation point of $(u_n)$. Then there is a subsequence of $(u_n)$ with limit $b$. This subsequence contains a monoton subsequence, by 1.

Hence: $b=a$.

Conclusion: $(u_n)$ is bounded an has exactly one accumulation point.